# Swift: Coordinates not accurate when using latitude/longitude

Tags: swift, core-location, coordinate

I'm using the CLLocationManager in Swift.
When I display location.coordinate, it provides me with the result:

37.787358900000001, longitude: -122.408227

However, if I display. location.coordinate.latitude, the result is

37.7873589

Do you know how I can get all the decimals?

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Actually, if I've understood correctly, this is only a matter of millimeters?

Comment: The extra decimals are a result of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: do you use "Float" type variable for lat long, or "CLLocationDegrees"?

Comment: Changing the last `9` to an `8` would result in a change of about 1 centimeter.  The GPS system is not accurate to even that level, so worrying about decimal places beyond that is pointless.

Comment: Makes good sense. I'll just go with the 'short' version then. Thanks, guys :)

Comment: By the way, do you know why the altitude keeps updating/changing, even when the device is standing still on a table?

Comment: http://gpsinformation.net/main/altitude.htm

Comment: Great stuff, thanks :)

Comment: @ThomasTe, I added an answer that summarizes all of the comments.  It includes a link to an article in IEEE about Broadcom's new chips for more accurate GPS.  It is unknown when Apple will use more accurate chips in the iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing `37.787358900000001` instead of `37.7873589` because of the [nature of representing floating point numbers in a computer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

That said, it is pointless to worry about decimal places beyond the 6th position because even changing the `9` to an `8` would result in a change of about `1` centimeter.  The GPS system is currently accurate to about +/- 5 meters, and with new chips [being deployed by Broadcom](https://spectrum.ieee.org/tech-talk/semiconductors/design/superaccurate-gps-chips-coming-to-smartphones-in-2018) that can be reduced to about +/- 30 centimeters in the near future.

> By the way, do you know why the altitude keeps updating/changing, even
>   when the device is standing still on a table?

Altitude calculations are done by computing the distance to the visible GPS satellites which orbit the Earth every 12 hours.  Since the satellites are constantly moving, and different satellites come into view, these calculations do tend to fluctuate.  [This article](http://gpsinformation.net/main/altitude.htm) though a bit dated is enlightening.